# Copy previous values kettle pentaho

Tags: integration, pentaho, etl, kettle, pdi

I have an issue and i'm looping on it! :| I hope someone can help me..

So i have an input file (.xls), that is simple but there are a row (lets say its "ROW1") that is like this:

1. ROW1 | ROW2 | ROW3 | ROW_N
2. 765 | 1 | AAAA-MM-DD | ...
3. null | 1 | AAAA-MM-DD | ...
4. null | 1 | AAAA-MM-DD | ...
5. 944 | 2 | AAAA-MM-DD | ...
6. null | 2 | AAAA-MM-DD | ...
7. 088 | 7 | AAAA-MM-DD | ...
8. 555 | 2 | AAAA-MM-DD | ...
9. null | 2 | AAAA-MM-DD | ...

There are no stardard here, like you can see.. There are some lines null (ROW1) and in ROW2, there are equal numbers, with different association to ROW1 (like in line 5 and 6, then in line 8 and 9).

My objective is to copy and paste the values from ROW1, in the ROW1 after when is null, till isn't null. Basically is to copy form previous step, when is null...

I'm trying to use the "Formula" step, by using something like:

=IF(AND(ISBLANK([ROW1]);NOT(ISBLANK([ROW2]));ROW_n=ROW1;IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK([ROW1]));NOT(ISBLANK([ROW2]));ROW_n=ROW1;ROW_n=""));

But nothing yet..

I've tried "Analytic Query" but nothing too..

I'm using just stream a xls file input..

Tks very much, any help is very much appreciiated!!

Best Regardsd!

Comment: Looks like the only option currently is the `Modified Java Script Value` step. There is a Jira open to address this issue in the `Analytic Query` step, but it's not there yet. Give the Java Script step a try.

Answer (score 1):

Well i discover a solution, adding a "User Defined Java Class" with the code below:

`import java.util.HashMap;
private FieldHelper output_field, card_field;
private RowSet out, log;
private String previou_card =null;`

`public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{`

```
if (first)
{
    first = false;
    out = findTargetRowSet("out");

    output_field = get(Fields.Out, "previous_card");
} else {
    Object[] r = getRow();
    if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }

    r = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
    if (previous_card != null) {
        output_field.setValue(r, previous_card);
    }

    if (card_field == null) {
        card_field = get(Fields.In, "Grupo de Cartões");
    }

    String card = card_field.getString(r);
    if (card != null && !card.isEmpty()) {
        previous_card = card;
    }
    // Send the row on to the next step.
    putRowTo(data.outputRowMeta, r, out);
}
return true;
```

After this i have to put a few steps but this help very much.

Thank you mates!!

Comment: +1 for the resourcefulness. You can achieve almost anything with the UDJC step (User Defines Java Class)

Comment: Thanks @YuvalHerziger!! I agree about UDJC step. I just need to practice a little more my Java ;) Best Regards

Comment: You're welcome. Just keep in mind, UDJC's are addictive when you write transformations day-to-day. In 90% of the use-cases, it's simpler and more human-readable to use other steps and make it obvious for other developers to understand your intentions

Answer (score -2):

Finally i got result. Please follow below steps

1. Below image is full transformation screen.
   [image]
2. Data Grid Data will be like these. Sorry for that in my local i don't have Microsoft because of that i took Data Grid. Instead of Data Grid you can drag and drop Microsoft Excel Input step.

[image]

3. Drag and Drop one java script step and write below code.

[image]

4. Last step of transformation, drag and drop Select values step and select the columns.( These step is no necessary)

[image]

5. Final result will be like these.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, you put me on the right track, but your code isn't enough.

Comment: I would not use this solution, simply because it does not answers the needs portrayed in the questions. If you want to recursively manipulate rows, UDJC would be the default choice.